# Create function that with a parameter with multiple values, like lines in a csv

Tags: python, function

So I have two functions. The first takes a string parameter and converts it into spacy tokens.

```
def preprocess (texts):
   case = truecase.get_true_case(texts)
   doc = nlp(case)
   return doc
```

The next calls that function and processes the text into aggregated dictionaries.

```
def summarize_texts(texts):
    doc = preprocess(texts) #another function that took text and processed it as a spacy doc
    actions = {}
    entities = {}
    for token in doc:
        if token.pos_ == "VERB":
            actions[token.lemma_] = actions.get(token.text, 0) +1
    for token in doc.ents:
         entities[token.label_] =  [token.text]
    return {
        'actions': actions,
        'entities': entities
    }
```

So that when you call the function you'll get these results.

```
summarize_texts("Play it again, Sam")

output: {'actions': {'play': 1}, 'entities': {'PERSON': ['Sam']}}
```

The issue I'm having is that my functions only work with one parameter but will fail if give it a parameter that's a list of sentences such as:

["Play something by Billie Holiday",
"Set a timer for five minutes",
"Play it again, Sam"]

and I'm not sure how to get it to work the way I want it to.

for example if I called

```
summarize_texts(["Play it again, Sam", "Play something by Billie Holiday"])

output: {'actions': {'play': 2}, 'entities': {'PERSON': ['Sam', 'Billie']}}
```

However if I run

```
docs = [
    "Play something by Billie Holiday",
    "Set a timer for five minutes",
    "Play it again, Sam"
]
summarize_texts(docs)

output is:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-200347d5cac5> in <module>()
      4     "Play it again, Sam"
      5 ]
----> 6 summarize_texts(docs)

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/nltk/tokenize/casual.py in _replace_html_entities(text, keep, remove_illegal, encoding)
    257         return "" if remove_illegal else match.group(0)
    258 
--> 259     return ENT_RE.sub(_convert_entity, _str_to_unicode(text, encoding))
    260 
    261 

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: You can check if the input is a list or a string?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `type` of the input!

Here I am checking if it is an `str` or a `list`!

After that if it is a `str` I am creating a list with just one sentence!

Your output will be a list of results! [Here you just return the one result if there was just one input! -- optional]

`return result[0] if len(result)==1 else result`

```
def preprocess (texts):
   case = truecase.get_true_case(texts)
   doc = nlp(case)
   return doc

def summarize_texts(texts):
    if type(texts) is str: texts = [texts]
    result = []
    for text in texts:
        doc = preprocess(text) #another function that took text and processed it as a spacy doc
        actions = {}
        entities = {}
        for token in doc:
            if token.pos_ == "VERB":
                actions[token.lemma_] = actions.get(token.text, 0) +1
        for token in doc.ents:
            entities[token.label_] =  [token.text]
        result.append({
            'actions': actions,
            'entities': entities
        })
    return result
print(summarize_texts("Play it again, Sam"))
print(summarize_texts(["Play something by Billie Holiday", "Set a timer for five minutes", "Play it again, Sam"]))
```

Comment: Don't bother converting it to a list if passed a string, just require the caller to pass a list of strings. It's no big hassle to write `summarize([sentence])` if you have just one.

Comment: @kindall yeah True, but it's quite common these days. Modules are able to recognise input type. If this is something that is distributed to someone else, I think it's good OP is thinking of this. I also thought about what you said :P

Comment: @kindall I still get the error 'TypeError: summarize_texts() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given' ideally I'd want the return with the dictionary values for all sentences. I edited the original post with an example

Comment: You're not passing a list, but two arguments If you want to handle multiple arguments you could use `*args`.

Comment: @kindall ideally this is going to be used on a csv file in which each line is a sentence. The function is aggregating the tokens from each side into the dictionaries like I have above. The function works for a single argument but when I try to pass along a list or csv I get the error ```TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object```

Comment: Type checking is unpythonic…